# Using ElasticSearch and Kibana for Business Intelligence

Tags: elasticsearch, etl, kibana, business-intelligence, datamart

We are using ElasticSearch for search capability in our product. This works fine.

Now we want to provide self service Business intelligence to our customers. Reporting on the operational database sucks due to performance impact. At the run-time, calculating average 'order resolution time' for 10 million records would not fetch the results in time. Traditional way is to create a data mart by loading the operational data using ETL and summarizing it. Then use any reporting engine, to offer metrics and reports to customers. This approach works but increases total cost of ownership for our customers.

I am wondering if anybody has used ElasticSearch as the intermediate data surface for reporting. Can Kibana serve the data exploration, visualization need?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: We explored ETK. Our UX did not like the kibana UX as the persona invovled may not like the query/lucene syntax. UX was looking for drag and drop, more easy and intuitive. Eventually we end up using a BI tool embedded in our web UI. However, we are planning to use Kibana for ITOPS product as the persona involved is more familiar with the operations tools.

Comment: Revisiting the similar problem in a different product. Exploring Grafana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Superset seems to be an answer. https://superset.apache.org/docs/intro

Answer (score 0):

We have the same needs.
Tools like Qlik, PowerBI, Tableau require to increase the overall insfrastructure stack and where you are designin solution to bring abroad without the possibility to share anyting they could be not the best possible option in terms of both costs 
 & complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I have used devextreme by devexpress. Its server side approach using custom store is very efficient to handle & perform operations on large amount of data. In case of mysql and mssql db, I have myself performed grouping, sorting ,filtering, summaries on 10 million data using devextreme.